# Undefined Index: Upload location error in Expression engine 2.2.1

Tags: expressionengine

i am completely new in expression engine. i got a task to upload some pictures into a live website already created with expression engine, while trying to upload the new pictures via upload image in the "create new entry" page i was getting error upload failed: eror  after that i discovered that all previous pages under the channel i am supposed to put the new entry are all going blank

i turned debug to 1, and got this error:

*"A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: locations
Filename: channel_images/mod.channel_images.php
Line Number: 426
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: require(/www/eh16395/public_html/****/expressionengine/third_party/channel_images/locations//.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
Filename: channel_images/mod.channel_images.php
Line Number: 435"*

now i am all confused because the pages were working perfectly fine before:

**my observations are** : the upload location directory being pointed to contained no image and i did not tamper with that in any way, (how could it av been working before without the images in the upload location)

**what i did:** i uploaded the same images into that location and synchronized, i started seeing the images in file manager but not in the particular entries. all i see in the entry are just the alt tags for the images and on clicking on them they take me to the error:

*A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: locations
Filename: channel_images/mod.channel_images.php
Line Number: 426*

I have explained as much as i can i hope i can get somebody to help me out. thank you.

Comment: You might want to post to the EE StackExchange site: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com